# Determining week number on a 4 week cycle in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

We do patching of servers on a 4 week cycle starting the first Tuesday of the month on today/Wednesday and Thursday and I'm looking for a way to determine what number week cycle we would be on based on the current date.

For example first week cycle which has all three days the Tuesday falls on the 5th so wed(6th) and Thursday(7th) = week 1 and so on for the 4 week cycle.

But if the first Tuesday happened to be a 1st then in the month there would be 5 sets of these days. So no patching would occur on the 5th set of these days.

So I would like something like that would output the week number or display "no patching"

```
If week contains (Tuesday (maxdates 1st -7th), Wednesday (maxdates 2nd-8th), Thursday (maxdates 3rd-9th) = week 1
Then if week contains (Tuesday (maxdates 8th -14th), Wednesday (maxdates 9th-15th), Thursday (maxdates 10th-16th) = week 2
Then if week contains (Tuesday (maxdates 15th -21st), Wednesday (maxdates 16th-22nd), Thursday (maxdates 17th-23rd) = week 3
Then if week contains (Tuesday (maxdates 22nd -28th), Wednesday (maxdates 23rd-29th), Thursday (maxdates 24th-30th) = week 4 

Else "no patching due to take place"
```

But if the month didn't contain a 29th or 30th for week 4 then I would need to include the 1st and the 2nd.

This would ideally allow me to incorporate this in my daily task list without the fear of the tasks accidently showing up on a week where no patching is due to take place. The task list is pulled daily from a sql database.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @v datetime = getdate()

select 
    DATENAME(weekday,@v) weekday,
    @v date,
    case 
        when DATENAME(weekday,@v) in ('Wednesday','Thursday')
                AND 1 + ((DATEPART(day,@v) / 7) * 7) > 1
                AND (DATEPART(day,@v) - ((DATEPART(day,@v) / 7) * 7) between 0 and 2)
            then (DATEPART(day,@v) / 7)
        else 1 + DATEPART(day,@v) / 7
    end week_no
```